# Java: Serialization of large Guava Table object fails with out of memory error

Tags: java, serialization, out-of-memory, guava

I have a large `Guava` `Table` object that I am trying to serialize:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
Table<Integer, Integer, Double> pTable;
//
// Put lots of stuff into pTable
//
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pTable.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(pTable);
```

At the last line I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.growEntries(ObjectOutputStream.java:2346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectOutputStream.java:2275)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
```

Is there a fix/workaround for this?
Would it also work for deserialization?

By the way, `pTable` represents a dense matrix of size about 30000 X 30000 where any pair of integers, each of which is from the set of 30000, maps into a float "distance" between them. If there is a more compact way of representing this matrix than `Guava`'s `Table` that could be created in a reasonable time and allow for quick lookup, I would be interested.

Comment: Why not just use a `double[30000][30000]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java).

e.g.

```
java -Xmx16g pTableProgram.jar
```

However, if you are using [0..30000) as your row keys and column keys then a `double[][]` would use less memory and if you don't need the precision of a `double` then a `float[][]` would use even less.

e.g.

```java
double[][] pTable = new double[30000][];
for (int i = 0; i < pTable.length; i++) {
    pTable[i] = new double[30000];
}
//
// Put lots of stuff into pTable
//
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pTable.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(pTable);
```

Comment: Even if the keys are not directly the 0..30000 range, I'd still go with the arrays and use a `Map` to give the real values an index in the 0..30000 range. You can use a primitive `Map` from fastutil, Trove, HPPC, etc. to avoid the boxing and reduce the memory usage.